# Check whether the function is continuous at 0 - what went wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I have to check the whether the following function is continuous:

$$   \
     f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},~f(x)=\left\{
     \begin{array}{lll} 
         e^{1/x} &\text{if} & x < 0,
         \\
         0 & \text{if}& x \ge 0.
     \end{array}\right. 
     \
$$

Now it is obvious that the function is continuous in $(-\infty, 0)$ as a combination of 2 continuous functions as well as in $(0, \infty)$ as a constant function.

To prove continuity at $0$, I took a sequence that approaches $0$, such as $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Now if $g(x) = e^\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous in $0$ it must be possible to get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}~ g(a_n)) = g(0)$. So:

$$e^\frac{1}{x} = \exp\frac{1}{x} \rightarrow g(a_n) = \exp(1/\frac{1}{n}) = \exp(n)$$
$$\rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}~ g(a_n)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}~ \exp(n) = \exp(\infty) \ne g(0)$$

Note: I am approaching $0$ from negative n - I just couldn't find a propper visualisation for that in Latex.

Now my question is: why is this proof is wrong? The solution should be that the function $f$ is continuous at $0$, but I don't see what went wrong. Also because the function is not defined at $0$, I am not sure whether I could perform the limit to $0$.

Thank you for advice!

FunkyPeanut

Comment: If $a_n>0$, $f(a_n)=0$.

Comment: So take $a_n$ negative with limit $0$ and show $f(a_n)\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't test continuity with *one* sequence, you need to test it with *all* sequences converging to $0$. It's easier with theorems on limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{1/x}
\overset{*}{=}
\lim_{y\to-\infty}e^y=0
$$
The equality marked with $*$ is from the substitution $x=1/y$.

The limit on the right is obviously $0$.

Comment: Hey - thanks! That was what I needed to know. I can't test continuity with one sequence. Thank you very much I would have done that wrong forever!

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n \to 0$ and $x_n<0$ then $\frac{1}{x_n} \to -\infty$ and $e^{1/x_n} \to 0$.
So the left limit is 0. The right limit at 0 is evidently 0. Therefore the function iscontinuous at 0.

Comment: Hey, thank you so far that seems logical. But why can I let $x_n$ Approach $0$? The Definition presented in my script says that the sequence has to Approach $\infty$ which is also said on wiki: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences). Or maybe I just got that wrong?

Comment: But you want to check the continuity at 0, so the sequence has to converge to 0.

Comment: Hmm... so why are they letting n Approach $\infty$ when they want to proof continuity at c? (I am again refering to the Wikipedia article above)